# Google Chrome: use 1 font for every website

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, stylish

I am using Chrome for a very long time now and I happy with it. Unfortunatly they discontinued the DirectWrite option. This is hell for people that aren't using Clear type fonts. Most fonts are messy now.

I want a Stylish sheet that replaces all website fonts with Arial. So I want every website to display the Arial font. I don't know how to do it.

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you can do this through chrome settings, but I found a great extension [FontChanger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-changer-with-google/jgjhhoglgjdklldfgoffdiaceffijeke?hl=en) that does the trick